# AngularJs ngResource for nested api resurces with different endpoints

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, angular-resource

I have this endpoints

```
/clients/:id
/bills/:id
/clients/:id/bills
```

I'm trying to create some resources with angular-resource to represent my API.

#### Clients and Bills Resources

I created a resource for the clients,

```
.factory('Clients', function($resource){
   return $resource('/clients/:id')
})
.factory('Bills', function($resource){
   return $resource('/bills/:id')
});
```

Those worked fine.

#### The Problem

My problem is when I wanted to define a resource to represent the bills of a client calling the endpoint `/client/:id/bills`

I thought that this should be a **Bills** resource with a method `getFromClient()` or something like that, as it will return an array of Bills from the client. But I have already use the Bills name. And the endpoint is different to the one already defined.

Any idea how to structure this?

Comment: Why not passing two variables to the client? Something like **id** and **bills**? If you leave the last one undefined you just get everything from a certain client and if its true you only get its bills.

Comment: @Flek But if I pass variables to the Clients service is going to return `Client` resources instead of `Bill` resources (with the Clients methods)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what I was loooking for is now in Anguar 1.1

```
.factory('Bills', function($resource){
  return $resource('/bills/:id',{}, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      params:{
        clientId: '@clientId'
      }
    },
    'getFromClient': {
      method:'GET',
      params: {
        clientId: '@clientId'
      },
      url: host + "/clients/:clientId/bills",
      isArray: true
     }
   })
});
```

Now you can add a url property to the method declaration to override the main url.

If you want to go with a library that enable you to solve this problema and many others, you could try https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod

Here is an example:

```
.factory('Client', function(restmod){
    return restmod.model('clients', {
        bills: { hasMany: 'Bill' }
    });
}

.factory('Bill', function(restmod){
    return restmod.model('bills');
}

.controller('myController', function(Client){
    $scope.client = Client.$find(1);
    $scope.client.bills.$search();
});
```

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that explains this?

Answer (score 5):

Check the ngResource docs... Scroll down to the first example heading:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

It's kinda confusing because they're not doing it right in the example... lol

I believe it would look something like:

```
.factory('Clients', function($resource){
   return $resource('/clients/:id', {id:'@id'})
})
.factory('ClientBills', function($resource){
   return $resource('/clients/:clientId/bills/:id', {clientId:'@clientId', id:'@id'})
});
```

I haven't tested this, but I think that's right. =)

**UPDATE**

You would then access them like so:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Clients, Bills) {
    $scope.client = Clients.get({id:$routeParams.clientId})
    $scope.bills = ClientBills.get({clientId:$routeParams.clientId})
})
```

I also changed the name of the service to "ClientBills", as it is more specific to the task, and you may want a "Bills" service that doesn't require a client id...

Comment: Thanks thom and @max, I think is a good way to go if I need to go with angular 1.0

Comment: I think you'd want to call ClientBills.query(..) though, since it will be returning an array of bills